# show TableView data into another Window contains TextField in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have made Two Fxml file one contains TextField and another contains TableView. And it has its Controller class. I want to show data from TableView to TextField when mouse clicked action event is performed. But we didn't get the result it shows a lots of error like :

```
Jun 02, 2018 8:33:36 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.162
Jun 02, 2018 8:33:44 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not find stylesheet: file:/C:/Users/MdAzaz/IdeaProjects/JavaFxProject3/out/production/Stylesheet/style.css
Jun 02, 2018 8:33:46 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.162
Jun 02, 2018 8:33:50 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.162
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Company.CompanyTableController.Clicked(CompanyTableController.java:123)
    at Company.CompanyTableController.access$100(CompanyTableController.java:35)
    at Company.CompanyTableController$2.handle(CompanyTableController.java:108)
    at Company.CompanyTableController$2.handle(CompanyTableController.java:105)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The first Fxml file name CompanyLayout.fxml contains TextFields and it has its Controller class like CompanyController.java. It has Button name Find when i clicked on that button CompanyTable.fxml is opened which contain TableView. When i clicked on perticular row of TableView the data of that row will display on CompanyLayout.fxml which contains Textfields.

Find Button code for CompanyController.java is this:

```
 btnFind.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                    Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Company\\CompanyTable.fxml"));
                    Scene scene=new Scene(root);
                    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Stylesheet\\style.css").toExternalForm());
                    primaryStage.setTitle("Company Table");
                    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                    primaryStage.show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

TableView Code for CompanyTableController.java is this:

```
CompanyTable.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                Clicked();
            }
        });

 private void Clicked()
    {
        try
        {
            CompanyData categoryData=CompanyTable.getItems().get(CompanyTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
           CategoryID.setText(categoryData.getCompanyID());
            CategoryName.setText(categoryData.getCompanyName());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I hope you will understand this code so, please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample app that demos your question.

The key is passing data from one `Controller` to another. You can find info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml).

> Here is the key code:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SearchPanel.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            SearchPanelController searchPanelController = loader.getController();//Get access to the Controller
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.showAndWait();//Wait for the Search Controller to close.
            Customer tempCustomer = searchPanelController.getCustomer();//Get the selected customer from the Search Controller. HAVE A LOOK AT THE SearchPanelController!
            //Set the selected customer to the TextFields
            tfFirstName.setText(tempCustomer.getFirstName());
            tfLastName.setText(tempCustomer.getLastName());
            tfEmail.setText(tempCustomer.getEmail());
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

> Full App - Main Class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author sedri
 */
public class JavaFXApplication3 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Customer Class:

```
/**
 *
 * @author sedrick
 */
public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }


    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

> FXMLDocumentController Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author sedri
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {    

    @FXML TextField tfFirstName, tfLastName, tfEmail;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
            try
            {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SearchPanel.fxml"));
                Parent root = loader.load();
                SearchPanelController searchPanelController = loader.getController();
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                stage.showAndWait();
                Customer tempCustomer = searchPanelController.getCustomer();
                tfFirstName.setText(tempCustomer.getFirstName());
                tfLastName.setText(tempCustomer.getLastName());
                tfEmail.setText(tempCustomer.getEmail());
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

> FXMLDocument FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="484.0" prefWidth="667.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication3.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar>
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity">
               <children>
                  <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity">
                     <children>
                        <Label maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="First Name:" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfFirstName" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity">
                     <children>
                        <Label maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="60.0" text="Last Name:" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfLastName" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity">
                     <children>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="60.0" text="Email: " />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfEmail" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Search" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

> SearchPanelController Class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author sedri
 */
public class SearchPanelController implements Initializable {

    @FXML TableView<Customer> tvSearch;
    @FXML TableColumn tcFirstName, tcLastName, tcEmail;

    Customer selectedCustomer;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        tvSearch.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection)->{
            if(newSelection != null)
            {
                selectedCustomer = newSelection;        
                tvSearch.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            }
        });
        tcFirstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
        tcLastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));
        tcEmail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("email"));

        ObservableList<Customer> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Customer("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Customer("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Customer("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Customer("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Customer("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );
        tvSearch.setItems(data);


    }    

    public Customer getCustomer()
    {
        return selectedCustomer;
    }
}
```

> SearchPanel FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication3.SearchPanelController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tvSearch" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="tcFirstName" prefWidth="153.0" text="First Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="tcLastName" prefWidth="182.0" text="Last Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tcEmail" prefWidth="263.0" text="Email" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```